# Get style attributes with regex from html string

Tags: c#, html, regex

This is my html string:

```
<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: line-through; background-color: #ffffff;">100 gram n!uts</p>
```

I want to get the font-weight value, if there is one. How do i do this with regex?

Comment: With an HTML Parser. Do you consider using one?

Comment: @stribizhev no, I need to do it with regex

Comment: @petko_stankoski why do you *need* to do it with a regex? Regular expressions can't parse every input and HTML text is one of the cases where parsing works only in limited cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should solve it

```
(?<=font-weight: )[0-9A-Za-z]+(?=;)
```

Explaination:

`(?<=font-weight: )` the string previous to the result has to be **font-weight:**

`[0-9A-Za-z]+` the result contains only letters and digits, at least one

`(?=;)`  the first char after the result is a **;**

**Code:**

```
string Pattern = @"(?<=font-weight: )[0-9A-Za-z]+(?=;)";
string Value = "<p style=\"opacity: 1; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: line-through; background-color: #ffffff;\">100 gram n!uts</p>";
string Result = Regex.Match(Value, Pattern).Value; //bold
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use some HTML parser in future, you might want to have a look at 
[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery). Just install the NuGet package for your solution and use it as shown in my snippet below.

```
var html = "<p style=\"opacity: 1; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: line-through; background-color: #ffffff;\">100 gram n!uts</p>";
var cq = CsQuery.CQ.CreateFragment(html);
foreach (var obj in cq.Select("p"))
{
    var style = string.Empty;
    var has_attr = obj.TryGetAttribute("style", out style);
    if (has_attr)
    {
       // Using LINQ and string methods
       var fontweight = style.Split(';').Where(p => p.Trim().StartsWith("font-weight:")).FirstOrDefault();
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fontweight.Trim()))
           Console.WriteLine(fontweight.Split(':')[1].Trim());
       // Or a regex
       var font_with_regex = Regex.Replace(style, @".*?\bfont-weight:\s*([^;]+).*", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
       Console.WriteLine(font_with_regex);
    }
}
```

Note that running a regex replacement is quite safe now, since we only have a plain short string, with no optional quotes around, nor tags to care of.

If you need to load an URL, use

```
var cq = CsQuery.CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

This is really much safer than using [this regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3cp%5cs%5b%5e%3c%5d*%5cbstyle%3d%22%5b%5e%3c%22%5d*%5cbfont-weight%3a%5cs*(%5b%5e%22%3c%3b%5d%2b)&i=%3cp+style%3d%22opacity%3a+1%3b+color%3a+%23000000%3b+font-weight%3a+bold%3b+font-style%3a+italic%3b+text-decoration%3a+line-through%3b+background-color%3a+%23ffffff%3b%22%3e100+gram+n!uts%3c%2fp%3e) that is hard to read and is likely to fail with a huge input text:

```
<p\s[^<]*\bstyle="[^<"]*\bfont-weight:\s*([^"<;]+)
```

Comment: Please check my answer, I tried to provide as complete answer as I could. Certainly, there are other parsers you might consider: [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/), [Angle Sharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp). Use regex only when necessary, not just for every string-related task. There are strings and strings, you know.